# Filling Data For Partial View MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, partial-views, dbcontext

We're developing news website we're confused with some concept of usage. I'd like to ask and know better if possible. We've a homepage which may contain a lot of models at once so we're separating our homepage to partial views and we're planning to feed them with the appropriate models.

In one partial we're enumerating in categories that are not marked as deleted and we've two types of categories. One of them displays the latest post and the other displays 4 posts at once. We've achieved this actually but as i've mentioned we would like to know if there is a better way or if we're doing anything wrong because right now we're keeping the connection to the context open until the partial is rendered.

Here is the code for views

### Partial View Code (CategoryRepeater.cshtml)

```
@using SosyalGundem.WebUI.DatabaseContext;
@{

var categoryList = new List<PostCategories>();

var db = new SosyalGundemDb();

categoryList = db.PostCategories.Include("Posts").Where(x => !x.IsDeleted).ToList();
}

@for (int i = 0; i < categoryList.Count; i++)
{
if (i % 3 == 0 || i == 0)
{
    @Html.Raw("<div class=\"row-fluid spacer\">")
}

var category = categoryList[i];
if (category.PostCategoryType == 1)
{
    <div class="span4">
        <h3 class="title"><span>@category.PostCategoryName</span></h3>

        @{

    var article = category.Posts.FirstOrDefault();

    if (article != null)
    {
        <article class="post">
            <div class="entry clearfix">
                <div class="span6">
                    <a href="#" title="Permalink to Suspen disse auctor dapibus neque pulvinar urna leo" rel="bookmark">
                        <img width="225" height="136" src="@Url.Content("~/Content/uploadedimages/" + article.Media.ToList()[0].MediaContent )" alt="shutterstock_70184773" />
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div class="span6">
                    <h4 class="smallnewstitle">@article.PostTitle</h4>
                    <p>@(article.PostSummary.Length > 100 ? article.PostSummary.Substring(0, 100) : article.PostSummary)</p>
                    <div class="meta">
                        <span class="date">@article.PostDate.ToString("MMMM dd, yyyy")</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </article>
    }

        }


    </div>
}
else
{
    <div class="video-box widget span4">
        <h3 class="title"><span>@category.PostCategoryName</span></h3>
        @{
    int cati = 0;
    var firstPost = category.Posts.OrderByDescending(x => x.PostDate).FirstOrDefault();
        }

        @if (firstPost != null)
        {
            <h4 class="smallnewstitle">@firstPost.PostTitle</h4>
            <p>@(firstPost.PostSummary.Length > 100 ? firstPost.PostSummary.Substring(0, 100) : firstPost.PostSummary) </p>

            <ul>

                @foreach (var item in category.Posts.OrderByDescending(x => x.PostDate))
                {
                    if (cati <= 3)
                    {
                        <li>
                            <a href="#" title="@item.PostTitle" rel="bookmark">
                                <img width="225" height="136" src="@Url.Content("~/Content/images/dummy/shutterstock_134257640-225x136.jpg")" alt="shutterstock_134257640" />
                            </a>
                        </li>
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                    cati++;
                }
            </ul>

        }


    </div>
}

if (i % 3 == 0 && i != 0)
{
    @Html.Raw("</div>")
}
}


@{
    db.Dispose();
}
```

Comment: You guys are doing everything wrong if your view is looking like that. Wrap your database queries in a `Using` block and write all that logic server side. Data Access logic does not belong in the View

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Separate your concerns. You can see this project for start: http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/617361/Partial-View-in-ASP-NET-MVC

Controller

```
      @using SosyalGundem.WebUI.DatabaseContext;
public ActionResult SomeAction()
        {
            var model = new CategoriesModel
            {
                NotDeletedCategories = db.PostCategories.Include("Posts").Where(x => !x.IsDeleted).ToList(),
                DeletedCategories = db.PostCategories.Include("Posts").Where(x => x.IsDeleted).ToList()
            };

            return View(model);


        }
```

Model

```
public class CategoriesModel
                {
                    public List<PostCategories> NotDeletedCategories {get;set;}
                    public List<PostCategories> DeletedCategories {get;set;}
                };
```

View

```
@model CategoriesModel
@Html.RenderPartial("DeletedCategories", Model.DeletedCategories)
@Html.RenderPartial("NotDeletedCategories", Model.NotDeletedCategories)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Hi Jinava,

I would suggest bind Model to the View,

Like,

  public ActionResult CategoryRepeater()
        {
            var multiViewModel = new MultiViewModelModel
            {
                ModelForParialView1= new XYZ(),
                ModelForParialView2= new PQR()
            };

            return View(model);


        }



For the View 
@model MultiViewModelModel

And then PAss the views with the MultiViewModelModel.ModelForParialView1 and MultiViewModelModel.ModelForParialView2

You can perform all the model operations on the view.

And at the controller level perform all the database operations and release the database connection there itself no need to get that on the view.

Hope this explanation helps you.
```